# Is my custom loss function differentiable?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions, gradient-descent, torch

Consider the following loss function.

```
loss = ( ( torch.where(d > threshold, torch.sqrt(d), 0) * t ) + ( torch.where(d <= threshold, (1 - d), 0) * (1 - t) ) )
```

where `d` is a vector of distances and `t` is a binary vector for targets. My rationale behind this custom loss is that I want a `distance-based loss` that encourages the distances of the points to be close to a certain `threshold` value if the corresponding binary vector element is 1 and far if the corresponding binary vector element is 0.

However, the loss function does not work when I use it in my deep-learning model. Basically, the model does not learn anything with this loss function.

I think the `torch.where()` parts make the loss function non-differentiable. I wonder if there is an alternative way to implement this loss.

Comment: Why not triplet or Siamese loss?

Comment: I would suggest you use the same set up us in Binary Cross Entropy Loss. Here you have one part of the function for zeros and one part for ones. t x (do something when t=1) + (1-t) x (do something when t=0)